# SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY Error

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, tor

I am sending multiple requests with aiohttp using tor's http proxy (with aiohttp_socks)

After some requests are done I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 171, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 95, in get_market_pages
    async with session.get(active_link, headers=headers) as response:
  File "/home/mrlalatg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/mrlalatg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 504, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "/home/mrlalatg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 847, in start
    message, payload = await self._protocol.read()  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/home/mrlalatg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 591, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2745)
```

I can't find any information about this error, except the git discussion about a similar one - [github](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3535)

There I found a workaround ([link](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3535#issuecomment-483268542)) that I can modify to ignore this error, but it didn't work, the error is still there.

The modified version of a workaround:

```py
SSL_PROTOCOLS = (asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol,)
try:
    import uvloop.loop
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    SSL_PROTOCOLS = (*SSL_PROTOCOLS, uvloop.loop.SSLProtocol)

def ignore_aiohttp_ssl_eror(loop):
    """Ignore aiohttp #3535 / cpython #13548 issue with SSL data after close

    There is an issue in Python 3.7 up to 3.7.3 that over-reports a
    ssl.SSLError fatal error (ssl.SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data
    after close notify (_ssl.c:2609)) after we are already done with the
    connection. See GitHub issues aio-libs/aiohttp#3535 and
    python/cpython#13548.

    Given a loop, this sets up an exception handler that ignores this specific
    exception, but passes everything else on to the previous exception handler
    this one replaces.

    Checks for fixed Python versions, disabling itself when running on 3.7.4+
    or 3.8.

    """

    orig_handler = loop.get_exception_handler()

    def ignore_ssl_error(loop, context):
        if context.get("message") in {
            "SSL error in data received",
            "Fatal error on transport",
        }:
            # validate we have the right exception, transport and protocol
            exception = context.get('exception')
            protocol = context.get('protocol')
            if (
                isinstance(exception, ssl.SSLError)
                and exception.reason == 'APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY'
                and isinstance(protocol, SSL_PROTOCOLS)
            ):
                if loop.get_debug():
                    asyncio.log.logger.debug('Ignoring asyncio SSL KRB5_S_INIT error')
                return
        if orig_handler is not None:
            orig_handler(loop, context)
        else:
            loop.default_exception_handler(context)

    loop.set_exception_handler(ignore_ssl_error)
```

Comment: I'm curious, what version of Python and `aiohttp` are you using? I've also read through the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3535) you linked, but most comments indicate this is limited to Python 3.7. I'm running Python 3.8.12 with `aiohttp` version 3.8.1 (Windows 10) and seeing this problem as well (although I'm not using Tor)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help but I made a simple mistake of closing aiohttp.ClientSession whilst having more code indented below it. See if session is getting closed somewhere in the code.